# Gitlab snippets returning 404

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets

All over a sudden all my Gitlab snippets are inaccessible on a project where I am the maintainer even when am logged in.

There are available, I see them listed on the repository but accessing them returns 404 every time.

Is there a way to revert this?

Comment: I reported an issue on Gitlab as well. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/38068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue is that there's a wrong url in the snippets list.

**Issue**:

Missing user and project details.

*Actual snippet link*

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1234567

*Working snippet link*

https://gitlab.com/jdoe/hello-world/snippets/1234567

**Solution**:

Manually add the `<username>/<project>` like `jdoe/hello-world` into the link

Hope this saves someone else's day.